# is it possible to include stuff like Login/Registration/... into a Unity-app as well?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

a customer would like to have an app with "standard elements" like login/registration as well as a video player and 3D building elements.

Is it possible to build the complete app in Unity/Unreal Engine/... and build the login elements there or do I have to "mix" it, i.e. make the login/registration form native and then navigate to the 3D-stuff?

As the app should run on different platforms I would prefer implementing the login-stuff only once.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer for Unity only.

Unity does not include a web browser and its WWW class is really basic (it doesn't perform redirections for example). So if you want to have an unique form on a web page and use it in Unity, you'll have to open the platform's browser or buy a plugin to do it in app (or do it yourself, but I don't think you want to do that).

Another way to do it is to build your form inside unity and send http requests to your server. Unity provides enough UI elements to do this and the WWW class will allow you to send the necessary requests.

**So in other words, you can do everything you listed in your Unity app** (login/registration, video and 3D stuffs).

Comment: +1 for building the form inside unity and sending http requests. IMO it's the quicker way. Not sure if https:// is supported on android though which leave the form open for a mitm attack, so the safest option would be to send an encrypted password over an http:// connection on android.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a number of standard UI elements like TextBoxes, Buttons, Labels etc.

You can easily create a login/registration form as part of the unity app itself without the need to open/create browser. You can use WebServices (WS) to transfer login/registration details or, if that's your business model, use a local DB for that purpose. If you want to use WS, meaning you want login/registration to be stored on your server, I believe you can do this with Unity, although with some limitations. [WS in Unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Webservices_In_Unity)